# How to query database from a OOP point-of-view

Tags: php, database, oop, mysqli, pdo

**Hey Guys**

I know Stackoverflow is may not the right place to ask, if there's another Stackexchange group where
this question fits better, then please tell me.

So, I'm trying to learn OOP. I think I understand it quite good, but there's one thing I really can't figure
out what the right way is, and thats the handling of database.

So, I'm confused a bit of what should go in which class.

Lets say I've a db class. Inside of this class I'm connecting to the database in a constructor. And now lets say
I've got a user class.

So now the question:
Where should I put in the query for example creating a new user? Should i create a method in the user class,
or should I create a method in the DB class? If in DB class, should it really be a method like `create_user()`
or should it more be something globally like `query` where I can pass in whatever query I want.

Here, for example a project from Github:

```
https://github.com/christran/PHP-OOP-Login-Register-System/blob/master/classes/user.php
```

As you can see, all query methods are in db.php and from user.php he's just calling this methods. So is this the right way to go?

Or doesn't it matter at all? May, any of those approches is "more" OOP than the other?

It's actually just really confusing me and I don't understand whats the better way. I've searched a lot, but never
found an article to this specific question.

So what I did, I looked for projects on Github and looked at their code, how they've solved the problem... 
But with this method I just got confused even more, because you see both.

Is it just a preference of the coder?

**I am really thankful for all your help. Have a nice day! :)**

Here a little example of what I mean:

Query inside user class:

```
class user {
    private function createUser() {
        //SQL Query here (prepared statements etc...)
    }
}
```

OR:

```
class user {

    private function createUser() {
        // Call to db.class to insert_method() ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Object-relational mapping isn't OOP. OOP is about decomposing a system into communicating state machines. ORMs are about reinventing network data models because developers don't understand the relational model of data. Databases are best viewed as representers of facts, not representers of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are looking into ORM.

To answer your question specifically,

> Should i create a method in the user class

This is possible, and is called Active record pattern, where an entity contains not only methods related to itself (like `$user->getBirthday()`) but also methods that related to database interaction (like `$user->save()`).

> or should I create a method in the DB class?

This is impossible, as this class will become enormously big.

However, you can create a sister class for the every entity, that will be responsible for the database interaction. This approach is called Data Mapper pattern. For example, there is a User class that contains methods related to the user, and also a UserMapper class, that is inherited from abstract  mapper class with generic methods `$userMapper->save()`, `$userMapper->find()` and such.

Comment: I've a question to this one. I just looked at the linked github repo from OP and took a look at the db class. https://github.com/christran/PHP-OOP-Login-Register-System/blob/master/classes/db.php The class is quite short, since he only has a "insert" method and pass the query to the metod. So one method for all querys. So this way, the class won't get to big. Is that bad practice?

Comment: @Twinfriends sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Okay, let me try it again. :P If you go on the linked git repo in my comment, you'll look at a db.php file. Scroll down to line 73. There is a method called "insert" - a method that inserts data in the db class. And every single query in the whole project is handled by this method. Is this good or bad practice? As you can see, he passes the tablename and a key-value pair to the function. This is the only function in the whole project who inserts data to database. Thats my question, if thats a good idea, or if I should create more method like createUser, createItem etc.

Comment: @Twinfriends well it doesn't look very object way. From what I can tell, you don't want to use a User class, but just run SQL queries all over the code using only DB class. Well, it's possible of course, but it's rather off topic here as the OP is asking regarding his User class specifically.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to answer me :)

Answer (score -1):

The createUser method that contains the query shouldn't be part of the User object, but neither of the database object. The first one is for business logic. The latter one is for managing the database method and providing generic functionality for executing statements. A different object inbetween those objects should be the one that takes the data from the user object and generate the queries for storing it in the database.

The term I think you're looking for here is [ORM (Object-relational mapping)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

This concept is about mapping objects to a different, incompatible structure, like a database.

There are ORM libraries/frameworks available for PHP which can do much of the work for you, and some of them are part of, or can be used with, popular MVC frameworks like [Eloquent ORM in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent). For example, they will often provide the basic [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations by implementing the SQL statements needed after you just configure the right database table.

In terms of OOP, you will often have an extra layer on top of it. So you got a business object User, which contains the rules for users, for instance rules it has to follow for a user name. The business object will enforce those rules and contain the general behaviour of a User object. For saving you make use of an ORM to save a user object to a specific database. The database logic is not in the User object itself. It shouldn't have to know about the specific queries to save itself, and maybe it shouldn't even be aware of concepts like loading and saving. It just contains logic and data, and other parts of the implementation are responsible for persisting that data (optionally using an ORM framework to make things easier).